# linear layout inside listview linear layout

Tags: java, android

I have a list view , each item of my list view having again list of dynamic data to display, when I am trying to inflate a linear layout inside listview linear layout inflating only the last item.

How can I do this?
Can anyone help me?

for (RoomCategory room : hotelInfo.roomCategory) {

```
            final View roomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_hotel_room, null);
            final TextView type = (TextView) roomView.findViewById(R.id.item_hotel_type);
            final TextView desc = (TextView) roomView.findViewById(R.id.item_hotel_desc);
            final TextView price = (TextView) roomView.findViewById(R.id.item_hotel_price);

            for (RoomType roomType : room.roomType) {


                type.setText(room.name + " - "+ roomType.type);


                for (Rate rates : roomType.rates) {

                    for (RoomSeq roomSeq : rates.roomRate.roomSeqs) {

                        price.setText(currency + " -" + TravflexUtil.friendlyPrice(roomSeq.roomPrice));

                    }

                }
            }

             views.rooms.addView(roomView);
        }

     }
```

Please refer this code

Comment: post your code..

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand very well your problem, try check this guide [Exercise: ListActivity with custom layout](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).